# Propel ORM - how do I specify tables to reverse engineer?

Tags: schema, reverse, propel

I have a database with a few dozen tables. My app deals with just one of those tables.  I'd like propel to generate the schema just for that table.  Is there a way I can specify the table(s) in build.properties?

Comment: I would rather not reverse engineer your database with Propel. Since you only need one table, I would write a `schema.xml` from scratch containing only this single table making sure the schema definition matches the table structure in the DB. I would set the `skipSql` attribute to `true`, so the table wouldn't even get altered by Propel. If everything matches, Propel will generate only the classes associated with that table. Of course, if you plan to write to the table, you might run into problems if the table is related to others.

Comment: Thanks. More generically, if my app uses a subset of the tables in the database and I don't want to create classes for the unused tables, is there a way I can specify the tables for reverse engineering?  The database schema is managed by a different group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to write your own schema parser that ignores certain tables. These tables to exclude could be read from a config file or so.

Take a look at the [MysqlSchemaParser.php](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/blob/master/generator/lib/reverse/mysql/MysqlSchemaParser.php) to get an idea of how such a parser works. You could extend such an existing parser and just override the [`parse()`](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/blob/master/generator/lib/reverse/mysql/MysqlSchemaParser.php#L86) method. When tables are added, you would check them for exclusion/inclusion and only add them if they meet your subset criteria.

How to create custom propel tasks is [described in the Propel cookbook](http://propelorm.org/cookbook/customizing-build.html).

Instead of invoking `propel-gen reverse` you would then invoke your customized reverse engineering task.

If done neatly, I'd find it worth being added as a contribution to the Propel project and you'd definitely deserve fame for that! :-)

Answer (score 2):

A simple extension of Propel (code examples based on Propel-1.6.8) to allow ignore a custom set of tables (configured using a property):

Extend build-propel.xml:

```
<!-- Ignore Tables Feature -->
<taskdef
name="propel-schema-reverse-ignore"
classname="task.PropelSchemaReverseIgnoreTask" classpathRef="propelclasses"/>
```

Extend build.xml:

```
<target name="reverse-ignore" depends="configure">
   <phing phingfile="build-propel.xml" target="reverse-ignore"/>
</target>
```

Extend PropelSchemaReverseTask:

class PropelSchemaReverseIgnoreTask extends PropelSchemaReverseTask {

```
/**
 * Builds the model classes from the database schema.
 * @return Database The built-out Database (with all tables, etc.)
 */
protected function buildModel()
{
    // ...

    // Loads Classname reverse.customParserClass if present
    $customParserClassname = $config->getBuildProperty("reverseCustomParserClass");
    if ($customParserClassname!=null) {
        $this->log('Using custom parser class: '.$customParserClassname);
        $parser = $config->getConfiguredSchemaParserForClassname($con, $customParserClassname);
    } else {
        $parser = $config->getConfiguredSchemaParser($con);
    }

    // ...
}
```

}

Add function to GeneratorConfig:

```
class GeneratorConfig implements GeneratorConfigInterface {
// ...
/**
 * Ignore Tables Feature:
 * Load a specific SchemaParser class
 * 
 * @param PDO $con
 * @param string $clazzName SchemaParser class to load
 * @throws BuildException
 * @return Ambigous <SchemaParser, unknown>
 */
public function getConfiguredSchemaParserForClassname(PDO $con = null, $clazzName)
{
    $parser = new $clazzName();
    if (!$parser instanceof SchemaParser) {
        throw new BuildException("Specified platform class ($clazz) does implement SchemaParser interface.", $this->getLocation());
    }
    $parser->setConnection($con);
    $parser->setMigrationTable($this->getBuildProperty('migrationTable'));
    $parser->setGeneratorConfig($this);

    return $parser;
}
```

}

Extend MysqlSchemaParser:

```
class MysqlSchemaIgnoreParser extends MysqlSchemaParser {

public function parse(Database $database, Task $task = null)
{
   $this->addVendorInfo = $this->getGeneratorConfig()->getBuildProperty('addVendorInfo');

    $stmt = $this->dbh->query("SHOW FULL TABLES");

    // First load the tables (important that this happen before filling out details of tables)
    $tables = array();

    $configIgnoreTables = $this->getGeneratorConfig()->getBuildProperty("reverseIgnoreTables");

    $tables_ignore_list = array();
    $tables_ignore_list = explode(",", $configIgnoreTables);

    if ($task) {
        $task->log("Reverse Engineering Tables", Project::MSG_VERBOSE);
    }

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        $name = $row[0];
        $type = $row[1];

        if (!in_array($name, $tables_ignore_list)) {

            // ... 

        } else {
            $task->log("Ignoring table: " .$name);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

}

Add new (optional) properties to build.properties:

```
# Propel Reverse Custom Properties
propel.reverse.customParserClass=MysqlSchemaIgnoreParser
propel.reverse.ignoreTables = table1,table2
```